# Check if an element is in a hashMap works with 'in' keyword but doesn't work with if conditional

Tags: python

I solved a simple Leetcode problem (that finds two numbers in a list that sum to a target number) in Python and found it curious why when I tried to change only one line to access the hashMap my code stopped functioning because of a KeyError. But I don't understand why the 'correct' way doesn't generate a keyError.

**The way that works**

```
  def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        hashMap = {}
        for ind, val in enumerate(nums):
            busq = target - val
            if busq in hashMap:  #This line is the only thing that changes
                return [hashMap[busq], ind]
            hashMap[val] = ind
```

**This doesn't work**

```
def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        hashMap = {}
        for ind, val in enumerate(nums):
            busq = target - val
                if(hashMap[busq]): #This doesn't work
                return [hashMap[busq], ind]
            hashMap[val] = ind
```

Comment: Because indexing a key that isn't in a dictionary raises KeyError, simple as.

Comment: Right.  The PURPOSE of the "if key in dict" statement is to avoid the KeyError that results from a bad key reference.

Comment: But why wouldn't the first method raise a KeyError? Some of the time, busq  won't be 'in' hashMap

Comment: The in keyword doesn't raise a KeyError. It returns False if the key isn't existing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access a non existing key in a python dictionary by using square brackets notation like `hashmap[busq]`, instead you should check for key existence before accessing it using `in` operator like in the first method.

You can also use `if hashmap.has_key(busq):` to check for key existence.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use something like this instead:

```
try:
    return [hashMap[busq], ind]
except KeyError:
    hashMap[val] = ind
```

When the key is not in the dict it will not return “False” but throw an error. So “if” will not work.